# Is there a $C>0$ such that $|z+\frac{z^2}{2}+\cdots+\frac{z^k}{k}|\leqslant C |z|^k$ for $|z|\geqslant\frac12$ for all $k$?

Tags: complex-analysis

In the proof of Hadamard's factorization theorem in Stein-Shakarchi's Complex Analysis, the following lemma is used

> [image]

Here is my **question**:

By using the triangle inequality and the assumption that $|2z|\geqslant 1$ I can work out a $c'$. But can the choice of $c'$ be independent of $k$ in the argument?

---

[Added to make my question more precise:] The book shows that given a positive integer $k$, there exists $c'>0$ such that
$$
|k+\frac{k^2}{2}+\cdots+\frac{z^k}{k}|\leqslant c'|k|^k
$$
for all $|z|\geqslant\frac12$. My question is: can $c'$ be independent of $k$, namely is the following statement true?

> There exists $c'>0$ such that *for all* positive integer $k$, 
>   $$
> |k+\frac{k^2}{2}+\cdots+\frac{z^k}{k}|\leqslant c'|k|^k
> $$
>   for all $|z|\geqslant\frac12$.

Comment: So $|z|\geq 1/2$ or $|z|\leq 1/2$?

Comment: @RobertZ: my silly typo in the title. Thanks!

Comment: So you got $c'=2^k\ln(2)$ and want to know how sharp that is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume that for some constant $c'$, for all $k\geq 1$ and for all $z\geq 1/2$
$$\left|z+\frac{z^2}{2}+\cdots+\frac{z^k}{k}\right|\leqslant c' |z|^k.$$
Then for $z=1$,
$$1+\frac{1}{2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{k}\leqslant c' $$
which contradicts the fact that  $\sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{1}{k}$ is divergent.
So such "uniform" constant $c'$ does not exist.

Comment: @Jack I revised my answer. Is it clear now?

Comment: Quick and nice. Thanks!